# how to convert value in a keypairs into list?

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
 dict.Add("key", New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("value1","value2"))
```

I want to get `value2` as a list.

Comment: Do you want value2 from entire dictionary?

Comment: yes exactly...tolist.

Comment: I think you already know, Linq in VB. did try using - dict.Values.Select(x =>x.Value).Tolist()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ Extensions:

```
' use KeyValuePair of dictionary, that gives 2 levels of KeyValuePairs
Dim list = dict.Select(function(kvp) kvp.Value.Value).ToList()

' Or use the Values part of Dictionary
Dim list = dict.Values.Select(function(v) v.Value).ToList()

' Adding some conditional and getting value1 instead:
Dim list = dict.Values.Where(function(k) k.Value = "value2").Select(function(v) v.Key).ToList()
```

For `KeyValuePair` `x.Key` is "value1" and `x.Value` is "value2"

Please note that this will get quite slow on big `Dictionary`s and there is probably better ways to handle this, but that requires more information about The actual use-case.

Comment: thx alot!! it works!! and how can i retrieve the value2 with value1 in dictionary.is it possible?

Comment: @ErolCimen Are you saying you want a list of KeyValuePair.Value (value2) based on what KeyValuePair.Key (value2) is?

Comment: i want to find all value1 by searching value2 in dictionary.

Comment: Dim list = dict.Values.Where(function(v) v.Value == valuetobefound).ToList().Select(x => x.Key).ToList()

Comment: `Dim list = dict.Values.Where(function(k) k.Value = "value2").Select(function(v) v.Key).ToList()`

`x.Key` is value1 and `x.Value` is value2

Comment: @Naruto double `=` is not used in VB and `function(x)` is needed instead of `x => ` otherwise it seems correct.